# Combining 3 tables to generate a list of profiles (HTML/PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, select, mysqli, join

I'm learning PHP/MySQL to provide info on/to local farmers through a website. Unfortunately, I have reached two seemingly tricky obstacles, which I'm struggling to overcome.

I have 3 tables, 'pro_list'(PRIMARY KEY **producer_id**), 'product_list'(PRIMARY KEY **product_id**) and an intermediate 'prod_to_prod'(FOREIGN KEYS **producer_id** and **product_id**) to enable a many-to-many relationship between the other two.

The idea is to generate a list of **div** elements containing info (e.g. phone, email, location...) taken from 'pro_list' and what they produce, from 'product_list', using their bridge with 'prod_to_prod' (as one producer can produce many products, and the same product can be produced by many different producers).

My problems start already with generating the basis query, which should return an elegant list of producers, using the bridge as a reference (i.e. I want the list to display only the producers whose **producer_id** has **product_id**s associated to it in 'prod_to_prod').
As you can imagine, the code I used...

```
<?php
$pagequery="SELECT * FROM pro_list 
            OUTER JOIN prod_to_prod 
            WHERE pro_list.producer_id=prod_to_prod.producer_id 
            LIMIT $offset, $num_of_cells";
$res_pagequery=mysqli_query($conn,$pagequery);    

while($proddiv=mysqli_fetch_array($res_pagequery))  {
echo "<div>
      ...Producer:".$proddiv['prod_firstname']."...
      </div>; 
}
?>
```

...has returned a list with numerous duplicates, as many **producer_id**s are associated with different **product_id**s in 'prod_to_prod'. I have tried numerous combinations using SELECT DISTINCT but, so far, all I've obtained where error messages.

I don't even know how to approach the extended query (i.e. display the names of the products associated to each producer in the corresponding **div**, based on the associations **pro_list.product_id=prod_to_prod.product_id** AND **product_list.product_id=prod_to_prod.product_id**. My guess is that I would have to work with UNION of at least two SELECTs, but since I'm only obtaining either duplicates or errors, I wouldn't even dare trying...

What would be your approach towards solving this?

Comment: They are probably not duplicates, per-say but the results of Cartesian products https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product  Its a common thing that happens, try adding `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 0):

When you do an (LEFT) OUTER JOIN you get at least one row for every Product whether or not there is a matching row in prod_to_prod. You want to change that to an INNER JOIN, which is actually the default -- you just use JOIN.

As you've noted, you will get a row in the result set for each match in prod_to_prod.

If you use `SELECT *` you are going to get all columns, but as you do not care about any of the columns from prod_to_prod, you can instead specify the specific columns you want or you can specify `SELECT pro_list.*`  In doing so, DISTINCT will be useful for eliminating duplicates, or you can use `GROUP BY pro_list.producer_id` to get one row per producer.